# CPACK : How to use CPACK_RPM_ADDITIONAL_MAN_DIRS varaible in Packing Man Files using CPACK?

Tags: cmake, cpack

CMake/CPACK Provides a way to pack Man files using **CPACK_RPM_ADDITIONAL_MAN_DIRS**  variable but the documentation is not so developer friendly.. Please help me with a sample snippet how we can use this variable for Packing Man files?
Currently I am Packing the Man files using **add_custom_command** , **add_custom_target** and **install** commands. It would be great if any help with a snippet is much appreciated for using **CPACK_RPM_ADDITIONAL_MAN_DIRS** variable. Thanks in advance!

```
set (man_dir ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/doc/)
set (man_dir_dst ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/doc/)

ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
    OUTPUT
            ${man_dir}/man.8.gz
    COMMAND gzip -c ${man_dir}/man.1m > ${man_dir}/man.8.gz
)

ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(
    BuildManDoc ALL
    DEPENDS
            ${man_dir}/man.8.gz
)

install(
    FILES
            ${man_dir}/man.8.gz
    DESTINATION ${man_dir_dst}
    COMPONENT bin
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your question! Can you please show the code for how you are *currently* packaging the man files? Also, please show what you have tried so far. Are you getting any errors or unexpected behavior from what you have tried?

Comment: squareskittles Thanks for your response.I have tried setting CPACK_RPM_ADDITIONAL_MAN_DIRS  to "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/doc/*" and i am not getting any error but the job is not done.

Answer (score 0):

The CMake [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/cpack_gen/rpm.html#variable:CPACK_RPM_ADDITIONAL_MAN_DIRS) for `CPACK_RPM_ADDITIONAL_MAN_DIRS` states the following:

> Note that in order to compress man pages a path must also be present in brp-compress RPM script

So it sounds like you *also* have to manually add the path `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/doc/*` to the list of paths in the `/usr/lib/rpm/brp-compress` script. The snippet from the script that needs modification is reproduced below:

```
# Add the path to this list of directories (bolded below).
for d in ./usr/man/man* ./usr/man/*/man* ./usr/info \
    ./usr/share/man/man* ./usr/share/man/*/man* ./usr/share/info \
    ./usr/kerberos/man ./usr/X11R6/man/man* ./usr/lib/perl5/man/man* \
    ./usr/share/doc/*/man/man* ./usr/lib/*/man/man* \
    ./path/to/your/cmake/proj/doc/*
do
...
```

On RHEL machines, the script to be modified is located here:

```
/usr/lib/rpm/brp-compress
```

but it's possible it is located elsewhere on different operating systems.

Comment: I have tried updating this and i am not sure how this works.. Because i did not see any change post setting the path in brp-compress as well.
Let me explain What i have tried so far..
    1) I have commented my existing working code and set (CPACK_RPM_ADDITIONAL_MAN_DIRS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/doc/*) 
   2)Later i tried adding the path in the brp-compress script and tried to build.
   3)I modified the path to match exact Man file , Man Dir instead of passing regular expression. These Changes i have done in both CMaklists.txt and brp-compress script.